# How to Incorporate Langchain Agent Response in Initialize_Agent Finished Chain Response?

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

I would like to incorporate the agent finished chain final answer in my LLM response. As you can see in the output of the model below, it doesn't output the agent final answer in the LLM response. If there is a better way to achieve this kind of output for agent and llm response I am all ears!

```
Observation: Final answer here with SQLResult: The available indices in the USA are:
1. S&P 400 Consumer Staples (Sector) - indexCode: 30
2. S&P United Arab Emirates LargeMidCap (US Dollar) - indexCode: SPCPMICAEUSD
3. S&P Qatar LargeMidCap (US Dollar) - indexCode: SPCPMICQAUSD
Thought:I now know the final answer.
Final Answer: The available indices in the USA are:
1. S&P 400 Consumer Staples (Sector) - indexCode: 30
2. S&P United Arab Emirates LargeMidCap (US Dollar) - indexCode: SPCPMICAEUSD
3. S&P Qatar LargeMidCap (US Dollar) - indexCode: SPCPMICQAUSD

> Finished chain.
'Would you like to select one of these indices?'
```

Code Snippet

```
from langchain.chains.conversation.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory
from langchain.agents import ZeroShotAgent, Tool, AgentExecutor
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory, ReadOnlySharedMemory
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.utilities import GoogleSearchAPIWrapper
from langchain.agents.self_ask_with_search.output_parser import SelfAskOutputParser
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout_final_only import (
    FinalStreamingStdOutCallbackHandler,
)

#prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["input", "chat_history"], template=TEMPLATE)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")
readonlymemory = ReadOnlySharedMemory(memory=memory)
tool_names = [tool.name for tool in tools]

model3 = "text-davinci-003"
deployment_id3 = 'text-davinci-003'

from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI


llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key= api_key,verbose=False, n = 1,deployment_id=deployment_id3, model=model3, callbacks = callbacks, streaming = True)


agent = initialize_agent(
    agent=AgentType.CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    tools=tools,
    llm=llm,
    #output_parser = SelfAskOutputParser(),
    verbose=False,
    max_iterations=3,
    #callbacks=callbacks,
    early_stopping_method='generate',
    memory=readonlymemory, 
    agent_kwargs={
        'prefix':TEMPLATE,
        'suffix':SUFFIX,
    }
)
```

Comment: is this possible even using intermediate steps? could i achieve something like printing the intermediate steps which would the observation or final answer then llm response?

Comment: if anyone is curious I completed this by adding return_dict = True in the tools initialization